# serverfireteam/panel validation:how to check for unique value in column

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel with serverfireteam/panel and I need that the validation checks for a unique value in column.
I tested this:

```
$this->edit->add('nr','Nummer','text')->rule('required')->rule('unique:nr');
```

result Query:

```
SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `nr` where `nr` = 22
```

and this:

```
$this->edit->add('nr', 'Nummer','text')->rule('required')->rule('unique:.kunden nr');
```

which results in:

```
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `kunden nr` where `nr` = 22)
```

Is it possible to check for uniqueness with rules in serverfireteam/panel and how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem. It's similar Syntax used like in laravel's default Syntax https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation.
But here you have always to add the tablename:

```
->rule('unique:tablename,columnname')
```

for example:

```
$this->edit->add('nr', 'Nummer','text')->rule('required')->rule('unique:kunden,nr');
```